# How to Secure an SOA style Symfony2 Application

Tags: security, rest, symfony, soa

So we're developing a web application in Symfony2 (brief editorial: Symfony2 is freaking awesome) along the lines of an SOA.  All data is farted back and forth between our jQuery powered frontend and the Symfony2 backend formatted a la JSON, and therein lies the rub.

Symfony2 provides for a robust security system, but it seems to hinge on the "Security Layer" intercepting form submissions and using the form-encoded POST data to process an authentication attempt.  This is problematic for our application because we use JSON exclusively.  From where I'm standing, using JSON for every single request and response *except* authentication is... the sheet of the bool, frankly.  Bad smell, bad juju, whatever you call it.

Now, Symfony2 allows for the creation of event listeners that hook into a series of events related to the lifecycle of a request and the consumate response.  We use one of these hooks to decode the JSON that comes in with every POST request so that the relevant controller only ever has to worry about working directly with a php array and not do any decoding or de-serializing or whatever.

So the crux of our issue is that the "Security Layer" expects that form-encoded POST data that it gets from a form submission (generally on a page that the backend served in the first place).  We're set up to feed it a PHP array created from JSONified data.  So what do?  Should we:

- Create a custom authentication service that is built to deal with an array made from le JSON?
- Tweak our request hook to check the target uri of each request and subsequently massage the request's JSON into the form-encoded string the "Security Layer" expects?
- Tweak the "Security Layer" so that it can work the the JSON turned php array?

Comment: +1 Welcome to SO. I love seeing questions like these that try to push a robust system even further. Plus, I like your 'sheet of the bool' line.

Comment: Where do you see that Symfony expects "form-encoded POST"? There are all kinds of authentication mechanisms implemented in sf2, form post is merely one of them.

Comment: @MDrollete Ah, well, that's a good question.  That detail _is_ specific to the form post method. Our line of thinking is such that the functionality of the form post method is closest to what we need to happen, namely that we can fire a data payload (le username and le password) at a uri and have the backend do the authentication dance with it.  The other methods suck (http auth) or involve a whole protocal layer that we really don't need (digest, x509).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple to create your own authentication provider. You can follow this [cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) and modify it slightly to handle your JSON request instead of the WSSE used in that example.

Comment: I'm liking this idea more and more.  Healthy _and_ satisfying.  We'll roll it out and see what happens!